# How can I integrate Monaco with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a fresh vue application and ran `npm install -s monaco-editor`, then I changed my App.vue to look like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="app" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
        <div ref="editor" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  async mounted() {
    const el = this.$refs.editor;
    this.editor = monaco.editor.create(el, {
      value: "console.log('hello world');",
      language: 'javascript',
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

When I run the application, I see the following in the JavaScript console:

```
Could not create web worker(s). Falling back to loading web worker code in main thread, which might cause UI freezes. Please see https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor#faq simpleWorker.js:31
You must define a function MonacoEnvironment.getWorkerUrl or MonacoEnvironment.getWorker 2 simpleWorker.js:33
Error: "Unexpected usage"
    loadForeignModule editorSimpleWorker.js:494
    _foreignProxy webWorker.js:54
languageFeatures.js:209
    _doValidate languageFeatures.js:209
```

I've tried searching for the error but most threads seem to focus on accessing files via file:/// which I am not doing (I'm accessing the node webserver).

Additionally, the editor does not render correctly unless height is explicitly specified - I don't think that's expected behavior.

How can I make monaco-editor work correctly in Vue? I would like to avoid unofficial third-party wrappers such as https://github.com/egoist/vue-monaco if possible for support reasons.

Node/Vue newbie, so please be nice!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Looking for an example myself.

Comment: No, I just added a bounty to the question though :)

Answer (score 6):

Try specifying the monaco `webpack` plugin in your webpack config:

```
const monacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor/webpack')

...

plugins: [
  new monacoWebpackPlugin()
]
```

Or install [monaco-editor-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin) and try using that instead:

```
const monacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin')

...

plugins: [
  new monacoWebpackPlugin()
]
```

As for the `height` and `width`, you can either listen to the window resize and call `editor.layout()` or calculate the container size and pass the size to the `editor.layout()` method <sup>[(1)](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/28)</sup>.

Or you can try something from other posted answers in similar threads, for example:

```
<div ref="editor" class="monaco-editor"></div>
```

```
.monaco-editor {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Or something like this:

```
.monaco-editor {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  max-height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: monaco-editor-webpack-plugin (from Microsoft) definitely works, but the first option `require('monaco-editor/webpack')` does not, on my install - there is no `/webpack` on `node_modules/monaco-editor`. How/what did you install?

Comment: @eric99 honestly, I can't remember if the first method worked for me or not, but for some reason I had it in one of my projects. I don't know, I just included it here

Comment: Ok - `package.json` of those projects might inform.

Comment: I found another (may be minor) gotcha. The editor size is not responsive. If say opening the devtools after initial load and changing width, the editor doesn't resize. I read somewhere that during `monaco.editor.create()` the editor gets it's size from the container element. Would be nice to get same behaviour as VS Code.

Comment: @eric99 you can just listen to the window resize and call `editor.layout()` or calculate the container size and pass the size to the `editor.layout()` method

Answer (score 4):

Monaco acceses workers by `file://` by default, but it is not work in web.

You should replace it with `http://` by setting MonacoEnviorment manually or using [Monaco Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin).

Refer to the [official docs](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/docs/integrate-esm.md)

Answer (score 4):

You need to match the **Vue CLI version** with **monaco-editor** and **monaco-editor-webpack-plugin**

**Vue2:**
Because vue2 is using webpack 4, we need to install:

```
npm i monaco-editor@0.30.1

npm i monaco-editor-webpack-plugin@6.0.0
```

**Vue3** (if you have Vue CLI 5 probably it is based on webpack 5. If CLI 4 solution is the same like for Vue2)

```
npm i monaco-editor (> = 0.31. *)

npm i monaco-editor-webpack-plugin 7.0.0
```

**vue.config.js:**

```js
const monacoWebpackPlugin = require("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new monacoWebpackPlugin()],
  },
};
```

Source:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2903